# Best way to use word lists for multi-language word game

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, plist

I'm very new in iOS programming and i can't find the best approach for my problem. I'm currently programming a multi-language word game and i have several dictionaries. I just need to use the words. I mean i don't need any description, synonym etc.

Is plist good enough for this? Or should i use sqlite or core data?

I've read lots of information about core data and sqlite in SO. But i can't decide which one is better way for me.

Any advice is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Taha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on number of words and your app's logic of retrieving data. If the number of words is not that large, you could use plist file. As for sqlite, while building your logic, you have take into account that you can not retrieve data from the database concurrently, e.g can't request data at the same time from different threads.

Comment: That's very helpful for me. One more question about plist. What is the max limit for plist? I have approximately 50.000 words for each language.

Comment: There is no such a limit, I think. The only limit on this case would be the memory, as if you load all those words to the array, you can get memory warning, or even app crash without memory warning.